# Lua gsub expression to rename variables in a Lua script

Tags: lua, gsub

I would like a gsub pattern to rename variables in a Lua script. Say I wanted to rename `x` to `y`.

`scr = scr:gsub(...,'y')`

Where `...` would find instances of x that are not beside any underscore, letter, or number.

EDIT: Here's an attempt

```lua
-- should be replaced?
--  yes   yes   no      no      yes   yes  yes    yes   no    no     no     yes
s = 'unc unc function FUNCTION :unc: .unc. -unc- =unc=  unc1 unc_ \' unc\' unc'
print(s:gsub('([%A?%-?])(unc)([%W?%-?])', '%1XXX%3'))
-- need to fix the start or beginning of string
--    could easily pad the string with a space then remove
-- also missing underscores and strings (ie dont replace between quotes) though..
-- tried ^_? (not 0 or 1 underscore) but it didn't work
```

`> unc XXX function FUNCTION :XXX: .XXX. -XXX- =XXX=  unc1 XXX_ ' XXX' unc`